# How to get checkboxes to repopulate using xenforo options

Tags: php, checkbox, admin, xenforo

Im using the following function in XenForo and the checkboxes are created for each node and the chosen options are saved in the db, but when the option is reloaded, the saved values are not being repopulated in the form.

Option:

```php
<option option_id="hc_watched_forums_list" edit_format="callback" data_type="array" can_backup="1">
<default_value>a:6:{i:0;s:1:"4";i:1;s:1:"5";i:2;s:1:"6";i:3;s:1:"7";i:4;s:2:"36";i:5;s:2:"38";}</default_value>
            <edit_format_params>HotCopper_Option_NodeChooser::renderCheckbox</edit_format_params>
<sub_options>*</sub_options>
<relation group_id="hc_misc_options" display_order="3306"/>
</option>
```

Function: (simplified)

```php
class HotCopper_Option_NodeChooser extends XenForo_Option_NodeChooser
{
    public static function renderCheckBox(XenForo_View $view, $fieldPrefix, array $preparedOption, $canEdit)
    {
        return self::_render('option_list_option_checkbox', $view, $fieldPrefix, $preparedOption, $canEdit);
    }
}
```

Can you suggest why its not repopulating the checkboxes and what I can do to fix it.
Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming you're not adding them using XML and that you are using the debug mode UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overrode original xenforo node model and option.
The option just needs to be changed to call the new model, and the model needed the selected to check if the nodeid was in the value array.

```php
public static function getNodeOptions($selectedForum, $includeRoot = false, $filter = false)
    {
        /* @var $nodeModel HotCopper_Model_Node */
        $nodeModel = XenForo_Model::create('HotCopper_Model_Node');

        $options = $nodeModel->getNodeOptionsArraySelectedArray(
            $nodeModel->getAllNodes(),
            $selectedForum,
            "Choose Required Forums"
        );

        if ($filter)
        {
            foreach ($options AS &$option)
            {
                if (!empty($option['node_type_id']) && $option['node_type_id'] != $filter)
                {
                    $option['disabled'] = 'disabled';
                }

                unset($option['node_type_id']);
            }
        }

        return $options;
    }
```

```php
public function getNodeOptionsArraySelectedArray(array $nodes, array $selectedNodes, $includeRoot = false)
    {
        $options = array();

        foreach ($nodes AS $nodeId => $node)
        {
            $node['depth'] += (($includeRoot && $nodeId) ? 1 : 0);

            $options[$nodeId] = array(
                'value' => $nodeId,
                'label' => $node['title'],
                'selected' => (in_array($nodeId,$selectedNodes)),
                'depth' => $node['depth'],
                'node_type_id' => $node['node_type_id']
            );
        }

        return $options;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `_render` method in the `XenForo_Option_NodeChooser` class expects there to be only one selected node, so it expects the value to be a single unsigned integer `node_id`.

As you're passing it an array, it doesn't work.

You would have to create your own standalone method to add in this option.